# Qiskit: mpl drawer module

Tags: python, jupyter, qiskit

I started using Qiskit with their official tutorial (Sezon 1) and I got a few bugs with the same code, at the beginning I just had to install pylatexenc but then I had "module 'qiskit.circuit' has no attribute 'draw'" error, this is not true as I used it before, I found some things about it on GitHub but no clear solution, my code is:

```
from qiskit import *
qr = QuantumRegister(2)
cr = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit.draw()

[it worked, output:

      
q0_0: 
      
q0_1: 
      
c0: 2/
      ]

circuit.h(qr[0])
[output: <qiskit.circuit.instructionset.InstructionSet at 0x12dc159de50>]

circuit.draw(output= 'mpl')

error: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4b6f233c71ed> in <module>
----> 1 circuit.draw(output= 'mpl')

AttributeError: module 'qiskit.circuit' has no attribute 'draw'
```

I use jupiter and Python 3.8, if version is wrong please tell me what version should I use and where do I download it, also, the output in first `circuit.draw()` is for some reason different than in original video

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69024137/16784108

Answer (score 8):

After installing
pip install pylatexenc

you must restart your notebook kernel and run again. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this liveries, but I ran your code in Colab and it said I needed to install `pylatexenc`, so I did and got the following output.

> MissingOptionalLibraryError: "The 'pylatexenc' library is required to use 'MatplotlibDrawer'. You can install it with 'pip install pylatexenc'."

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about this genre, so I can't give you a detailed answer. If my answer is helpful to you, please click the check mark to accept the answer!

Comment: If you've already done this, it's beyond my scope. I checked further and found a similar issue reported on github. See here for [reference](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/6094).

Comment: @ql h `from qiskit import *;qr = QuantumRegister(2);cr = ClassicalRegister(2);circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr);circuit.draw('mpl')` The link, which should have already been made private, was intact. The code is as follows